# My button has to be tapped twice before my text is appended to my tableView

Tags: swift, keyboard, tableview

I have a UITextView and a Button programmatically constrained in a UIView when the text view is tapped the keyboard shows up and the view moves up with the keyboard as I want it to as I have functions that deal with this

My issue is when I put in some text into the UITextView I have to tap the button twice before the function I have set is called and the table view shows the data

Does anyone know the reason why this is happening and why it doesn't work the first time I tap the button here is my code

```
var message = [String]()

let messageView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    return view     
}()

let sendButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle(" send", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.green, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSend), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func handleSend() {
      message.append(messageTextView.text)
      tableview.reloadData()
}

let messageTextView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.textColor = .black
    textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)

    return textView
}()

let line: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .gray
    return label
}()

let tableview: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView()
    tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tv
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    constraints()
    hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self
    tableview.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableview.separatorStyle  = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none

   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name:       UIWindow.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: UIWindow.keyboardWillHideNotification, 

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return message.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->     UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell


    cell.textLabel?.text = message[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Is this your real code? I don't understand what text view we are even talking about. Your code _makes_ a UITextView, `messageTextView`, but you never put it into the _interface_. So how does its text even change?

Comment: Try to reload table in main thread, where the sendButton  is added?

Answer (score 1):

I come across this type of issue in many different areas, not only relating to the keyboard.

I've found the best solution is to put the funcs in a queue, 1 millisecond is even enough!.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1), execute:
        {
             // YOUR CODE WILL BE EXECUTED IN THIS BLOCK
        })
```

This DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter has helped me solve many problems when the code should work but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Though your code is unclear, but I think I've figure out why you might be facing this issue.
I see you have a method call `hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()` , here if you are using `UITapGestureRecognizer` you may want to set `cancelsTouchesInView` to `false`.

When this property is `false`, the view receives all the touches in the multi-touch sequence which is not in the case of it's default state which is `true` where previously delivered touches are cancelled.